# Preference items and explicit intents

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to call an activity from a Preference item

Ideally I'd like to simply specify an explicit intent in the xml for that Preference item

but my google fu has deserted me and I can only find examples of implicit intents, e.g.

```
<Preference android:title="@string/prefs_web_page" >
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="http://www.example.com" />
</Preference>
```

I have already called my activity elesewhere programatically, e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FileChooserActivity.class);
```

but I want to call this direct from the xml

is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: @ webnetmobile.com - can i have your answer back? it looked useful, jsut remove the bit about not being able to call intents from xml so you don't get down-voted

Comment: See Dj S response below. Seems that should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

Add this to your Preference XML:

```
<Preference
  android:key="TODO"
  android:title="@string/TODO"
  android:summary="@string/TODO">
    <intent
      android:action="com.example.test.pref.action"/>
</Preference>
```

And add this in your Manifest to Activity to be opened from Preferences:

```
<activity android:name=".todo"
  android:label="@string/todo">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.test.pref.action" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Make sure **com.example.test.pref.action** is unique!

**Note:**
If you need to open a Website or any Activity whose Manifest entry you can't edit, you'll need to programatically open it from your Activity com.example.test.pref.action with an Intent.

Comment: I assume opening an activity from a Preference item is a very common thing to do in android development. Is the 'de-facto' approach to do it in xml or programatically from within the Activity.java? How would you do it?

Comment: If you need to open your own Activity, I'd do it from XML as shown. If you need to open a Webpage instead, I'd do it programmatically to avoid creating another Activity just for this.

Comment: This is not the right answer to the question. See Dj S response below.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the currently selected answer is not an explicit Intent, but an implicit one.
To make it an explicit Intent,

your preference XML should look like this (define targetPackage and targetClass):

```
<Preference android:title="@string/preference_title__intent_act" >
    <intent 
        android:targetPackage="com.mycompany.mypackage"
        android:targetClass="com.mycompany.mypackage.IntentActivityFromPreferences" />
</Preference>
```

Your activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml should look like this:

```
<manifest 
    ...
    package="com.mycompany.mypackage">
    ...
    ...
        <activity 
            android:name="com.mycompany.mypackage.IntentActivityFromPreferences"
            android:label="@string/activity_intentactivityfromprefs_name">
        </activity>
</manifest>
```

Notes:

- "com.mycompany.mypackage" is the root package declared in AndroidManifest.xml
- If target class is not inside "com.mycompany.mypackage", it is also OK, just make sure that the declaration in AndroidManifest.xml is correct

Comment: This is the absolutely correct answer for the question!
The marked answer is not an explicit intent which by definition "specify the component to start by name (the fully-qualified class name)".

Answer (score 5):

targetPackage and targetClass are the properties you search.

You can use this :

```
<intent
    android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
    android:targetPackage="com.example.package"
    android:targetClass="com.example.package.FileChooserActivity" />
```

Comment: does it make sense to specify an action for an explicit intent? and is targetClass the same as componentName? I would have thought that targetPackage was superfluous as well?

Comment: i think targetPackage is required. The action, i'm not quite sure.

Comment: You _may_ and _should_ leave out the `android:action` attribute if specifying an explicit `Intent`. Tested on devices from Android 2.2 to Android 4.1.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure of that. Your activity could have several intent-filters and perform different actions based on android:action.

Comment: No, you can leave out `android:action` if you use both `android:targetPackage` and `android:targetClass` to specify an explicit `Intent`. But if you want to use an implicit one, you usually just set `android:action` - and you _may_ also set `android:targetPackage` so that only one specific application (package) may handle that `Intent`.

Comment: what value would i get in onCreate for the intent action in this case?

Comment: Explicit intents do not require the action attribute. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html