# ActivityNotFoundException when trying to invoke an 'explicit' intent from Preferences, to open an Activity in default package?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-preferences, activitynotfoundexception, android-preference-v14

In the following SSCCE I am trying to invoke an *explicit* intent from `preferences.xml`, to open an Activity which is located in the one and only package in the app, in which all Activity's are located.

But I get the following exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  }
```

*I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360100/activitynotfoundexception-when-different-packages-targetclass-in-preferencescre) but it is about starting an Activity in another package, and somebody said in that question that their app to open Activity in default package works fine.*

Following are the relevant parts of code.

**NOTE:** Since `SecondActivity` is in the same package as the `MainActivity`, I initially tried to use *only one* `android:targetClass` attribute to the `<intent>` in the preferences.xml, but then after the exception I added the `android:targetPackage` too, but that did not solve the problem.

**MainActivty.java:**

```
package practice.preferences_practice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

**preferences.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <Preference android:key="@+id/preferences_preference_preferenceContainingIntent"
        android:title="@string/preferences_preference_preferenceContainingIntent_title"
        android:summary="@string/preferences_preference_preferenceContainingIntent_summary" >


        <intent android:targetPackage="practice.preferences_practice"
            android:targetClass="practice.preferences_practice.SecondActivity" />


    </Preference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="practice.preferences_practice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**NOTE:** I have Not used an `<intent-filter>` in Manifest for the `SecondActivity` because it lies in the same default package as the `MainActivity`, which is `practice.preferences_practice`.

**NOTE:** If you think I should post all the other code files as well, please let me know.

---

---

---

***EDIT:***

**res/values/strings.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Preferences Practice</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

    <string name="preferences_preference_preferenceContainingIntent_title">Preferece Title</string>
    <string name="preferences_preference_preferenceContainingIntent_summary">Opens another activity because this preference contains and invokes an Intent.</string>

    <string name="title_activity_second">SecondActivity</string>

</resources>
```

**res/layout/activity_second.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F4A460"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SecondActivity.java:**

```
package practice.preferences_practice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are targeting SecondActivity but you are adding  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); in MainActivity.

Comment: @O'one "you are adding addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); in MainActivity" - because I want to add the preferences to the MainActivity. This is an example app and my MainActivity is the PreferenceActivity - it displays the list of preferences. 
"You are targeting SecondActivity" - Yes. The `MainActivity` displays a preference (there is only one preference item in this app, otherwise a _list of_ preferences would be displayed), and when the user clicks on the Preference (the only one in this case), the `SecondActivity` should open. **Am I missing something?**

Comment: add this inside preference and then intent tag.    android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"

Comment: also check if you are using fully qualified name.

Comment: also use only sub packages in the target class section.

Comment: @Solace your code seems fine, Keeping in mind the same use case you trying to implement I tried the same code and it's working fine. You can post other files to find the root cause of this issue.

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi (1) But why would I need an `action` for the intent? It is an explicit intent; I want to start one particular Activity (and I am providing its name), not-any-activity-which-could-handle-VIEW-intent. (2) I AM using fully qualified names as you can see in the preferences.xml file I provided (3) There is no sub-packages, only one package which contains all Activity's, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @O'one OK posting them in the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198831/preference-items-and-explicit-intents

Comment: @O'one I posted it all in the question. I also updated code of `MainActivity.java` to display package name and import statements

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi thank you for the link. Could you see the answer by Dj S, because the accepted answer shows an IMPLICIT intent (somebody has pointed it out there in a comment under the QUESTION)? Do you see anything in my code which differs from what is described in the answer by Dj S? Sorry if I am missing smething.

Comment: @O'one If you could run my code now and see if it works, I will be thankful

Comment: You code is as it should be. It's working pretty fine. Try to clean build the project and reinstall the apk. or connect with me over skype so I can check it by screen sharing.

Comment: @Solace the only difference is your declaration in manifest is not fully qualified, but i don't think it matters, try using fully qualified in manifest also, and then let me know.

Comment: @O'one Oh goodness it's working now. I did a clean build and restarted Eclipse as well. Thank you so so very much, I really appreciate your help. =)

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi Which declaration? That of `SecondActivity`? The `.` before `SecondActivity` means the compiler will automatically add the default package's full name there. And hey it is working now after clean build. Thank you for your time and help. =)

Comment: @Solace I would like to suggest you to use android studio for further development.

Comment: enjoy now :)  and yes start using android studio.

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi It shows down my already slow laptop =(

Comment: :(  if you are android developer upgrade laptop  (ram) :) and enjoy android studio :P

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi Yeah I have 3GB RAM right now, I am thinking of upgrading it to 8GB. But somebody told me that it has only two cores in its processor (which is core i3), so it won't be too fast.

Comment: i have i5, but when my system ram was 4gb it was too slow, and when upgraded to 8gb, now fine.

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi See, you have i5. I'll have to buy a new laptop. This one has a slow processor too

Comment: yes you are right :) btw I have bookmarked your profile page :) will ask you whenever i am stuck in code :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105784/discussion-between-solace-and-hammad-tariq-sahi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is as it should be. It's working pretty fine as I also tested it. Try to clean build the project and reinstall the apk.

Comment: Worked for me too. That said this answer feels incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));` to start second activity.

Comment: This DOES NOT answer the question. I know how to start an Activity from another Activity programmatically. The question is about _why doesn't an Intent specified in preferences successfully start an Activity? What am I missing? Where am I making a mistake?_ I suggest you remove this answer before it gets downvoted.